# Unable to target child element but fine on parent

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I am trying to target `a.click` in the below code with jQuery. When `a.click` is clicked, `p.excerpt` should slide down below it.

For some reason jQuery doesn't do anything when I target `a.click` - nothing happens when it is clicked. However, if I target the parent div the slidedown works fine.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="listing">
    <div class="col-xs-4 title">
        <strong><a class="click">The Title</a> </strong>
        <p class="excerpt">The Excerpt.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here' the jQuery that is not working:

```
jQuery( ".listing .title a.click" ).click(function() {
     jQuery( "p.excerpt", this ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
     });
});
```

Here's the jQuery that works fine:

```
jQuery( ".listing .title" ).click(function() {
     jQuery( "p.excerpt", this ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
     });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selector is in correct. Try:

```
jQuery( ".listing .title a.click" ).click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     jQuery(this).parent().next("p.excerpt").slideToggle( "slow", function() {
     });
});
```

You need to navigate to the parent of anchor and then the next element to it is the `p.excerpt` element. Using the syntax `jQuery( "p.excerpt", this )` you are looking for `p.excerpt` that are descendants of the `a.click` element. (`this` in that handler represents the anchor element)

Comment: Great, thanks for your help. BTW - what does the e.preventDefault() do?

Comment: @user1444027 It is just used to prevent the default behaviorof the anchor, useful when you have `href=#` most of the times in your anchor element.